# How to open multiple clearcase views in separate vscode sessions

Tags: visual-studio-code, clearcase

I am trying to work on two different ClearCase views in two VSCode sessions.

But, when I open the second instance of VSCode , it defaults to the first view and changing the view in the second session also changes the set view in the first session.

Is there a way to work on multiple views in separate VSCode windows?

Comment: Did you solve your issue regarding  multiple views in separate VSCode windows?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to work with ClearCase snapshot views, which are loading their files to a fixed path, one per view.
Then each VSCode session can register a VSCode workspace which opens its own dedicated folder, again, one per view.

A similar approach is possible with ClearCase dynamic views, provided you do not do a [`cleartool setview`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.0?topic=ucm-setview), which would attempts to mount each view on the MVFS mounting point `/view` (or M:\ on W: only one view at at time can be attached to `/view`.
Using setview would explain why the second VSCode opens files of the first view, if it attempts to open files mounted by the first view.

But for dynamic views mounted on distinct paths, the same scenario than snapshot view can apply:

- open the right root folder of one view
- save that as a **[VSCode workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces)** file
- when you reopen that file, you will reopen the right view files.